# Chrome Extension eval Alternative

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, eval

I've built a Chrome Extension that parses data from different websites, using website specific scripts. I want to add an option page in which user can write (and store) his own script for a web site that is not supported originally.  Chrome doesn't let me eval strings, what alternative route can I use? I think tampermonkey is doing something similar, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You could always look at the source code for Tampermonkey.

Comment: It doesn't let you call `eval()`? What about others such as `Function()` or `setTimeout("")` (ugly as sin, but could be a workaround).

Comment: Starting from [march 2013](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html) Chrome Store will limit, then refuse manifest version 1. So, neither `eval()` nor `new Function()` will be allowed any more. The only thing I guess is possibile to do is to relax the [CSP policies](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) with `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`.

Comment: There is a way to do this using the "tabs" permission and `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code: yourCodeString });` But it seems Tampermonkey is doing it some other way, because their userscripts' paths are coming from the background "userscript.html" page. I haven't figured out how they are doing this, but the method with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is working too

Answer (score 1):

See the article: ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html)

It describes how you can have a sandboxed iframe where you can run `eval` and communicate results to you extension using messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  [script injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) could help you